# What is the quickest input format to select what animals a user sees

Tags: ios, input-fields

I hope someone can suggest an efficient input format for a user to input what animals he/she saw and how many of each. It is for an iOS/Android app.

The idea is that the user can add by pushing the relevant row - and if more than 0 then a deduction button is showing on the right (red).

Do you guys have a better suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you figure these will usually just be a low number, perhaps an input control that allows incrementing and decrementing. Consider the follow example:

[image: numeric stepper]

This would allow your users to adjust their value by 1 with a single tap (probably a common use case), but also allows them to explicitly specify their target number.

Comment: Good suggestion.