# Football match score entry

Tags: forms, text

My team are working on a 'predict the scores of the games' promotion for our business.

We are debating how you enter the scores themselves, we have 2 solutions:

**A.** A button either side of the number to increase/decrease the number for the score.
**B.** A standard text entry field to enter the number.

Which is the best route?

Comment: Another possibility would be a strip across the width of the screen with the scores on: `_0__1__2__3__4__5__6__7__8__9__...` (probably with the ability to scroll in or switch to larger numbers on from the right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're talking about [Association Football (or "soccer")](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Association_football), the [average number of goals per match is 2.6](http://www.decisionsciencenews.com/2016/03/01/most-soccer-matches-are-within-one-goal-of-1-0/). This relatively small number would be a good opportunity to use steppers.

Your users could use something like the following (which I've recommended in [another answer](https://ux.stackexchange.com/a/117053/77811) as well):

[image: numeric stepper]

This allows your users to increment/decrement the scores to select their desired values, but also allows them to explicitly type it if they prefer.

[image: mockup]

<sup>[download bmml source](/plugins/mockups/download?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2frSmLn.png) – Wireframes created with [Balsamiq Mockups](http://www.balsamiq.com/products/mockups)</sup>

Comment: Do you think this could cause a cluttered UI, in particular for mobile?

Comment: Personally, I think I'd prefer it. That way, if I'm trying to add scores for several teams at once, I wouldn't have to bother with the keyboard potentially appearing and disappearing several times as I enter my score predictions. Again, I think the main thing working in your favor here is that the average number of goals per match is only 2.6, so really that's the average number of taps a user would have to do per score prediction. I'd say that's an acceptable number, but user testing would be enlightening here.

Comment: Added a mobile wireframe.

Comment: Ah yes I see your point. I think what you've proposed is spot on, the combination of the suggestions we have. Thank you for your answer :)

Comment: No problem! Obviously, make sure the buttons are large enough to tap easily... I realize the wireframe makes them look too small.

Answer (score 0):

Surely it'd be easier to have text input fields that automatically jump to the next input once a score has been entered?

See http://jsfiddle.net/4rj6rv5p/3/  (assuming no-one's going to enter a score bigger than 9)

Using the venerable [Keystroke Level Model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keystroke-level_model) that's only N Keypress operations (where N is the number of scores) as opposed to having to press the up/down spinners S times (where S = the total of all scores), plus the N mouse/finger navigations to each control